# Powershell Get-Date

Tags: powershell, script

I am creating an object in a powershell script that gets today date in the following format.

```
$TodaysDate=Get-Date -Format "MM-MMM"
```

The result shows the month as both a numeric value as well as the name value:

```
$TodaysDate

04-Apr
```

Is there a way I can take that value and somehow change the first to digits to a different value and then store that as a new object?

Example:

01-Jan Would become 04-Jan

02-Feb Would become 05-Feb

03-Mar Would become 06-Mar

04-Apr Would become 07-Apr

and so on .....

Comment: Why don't you just treat it as a date and add 3 days to it using a DateTime function within PowerShell?

Comment: Sorry. I should have specified that the 01,02,03,04, etc... are actually the month also and not the actual day.

Comment: You can treat the DateTime as a string and do a string replacement on the first 2 characters in that case.  You could string split the two strings, treat one as a integer and the other as a string, modify the int and recombine them.  But your request is a little confusing if `07-Apr` is supposed to indicate April is the 7th month.

Comment: Thanks! The new integer would actually represent a fiscal year month running from Oct (01)-Sep(12) Does that make sense? Do you have an example I could refer to to develop my script? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit annoying that -Format returns a string, rather than a DateTime with a specific format. Maybe, get each element separately, add three months to the first element, then get the string of each one and concatenate them:

```
(Get-Date ((Get-Date).AddMonths(3)) -Format "MM") + "-" + (Get-Date -Format "MMM")
```

Or something like that.

This also a really awkward date format. Accountants are weird.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much!